# jar ファイルを起動する方法

Tags: java, scala, sbt

## sbt-assembly を用いてビルドした jar ファイルを起動できない

---

### 環境

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.3
```

```
$ java --version
openjdk 13.0.2 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ scala --version
Scala code runner version 2.13.1 -- Copyright 2002-2019, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

```
$ sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.3.7
sbt script version: 1.3.8
```

---

## 状況

sbt は以下の表示

```
sbt:scala-gui> assembly
[info] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file (Run the task at debug level to see details)
[info] Strategy 'first' was applied to a file (Run the task at debug level to see details)
[info] Strategy 'rename' was applied to a file (Run the task at debug level to see details)
[info] Assembly up to date: /Users/tsubasa/Documents/scala-gui/target/scala-2.13/scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 26, 2020, 6:48:08 PM
```

いくつか出ている [info] が気になりますが、何のことか分かりません。とりあえず [success] ということなので、`target/scala-2.13/scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` を Finder (Jar launcher.app) から開くことにしました。

以下のダイアログが表示され、開けません。

[image: Check the Console for possible error messages.]

```
The Java JAR file “scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar” could not be launched.

Check the Console for possible error messages.
```

---

## コード

./src/main/scala/Main.scala

```scala
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.event.{ActionEvent, EventHandler}
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import javafx.stage.Stage

object Main extends App {
  Application.launch(classOf[Main], args: _*)
}

class Main extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit = {
    val btn = new Button()
    btn.setText("押してね")

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
      override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
        println("こんにちは")
      }
    })

    val root = new StackPane()
    root.getChildren.add(btn)

    val scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250)
    primaryStage.setTitle("コンソールにこんにちはを出力")
    primaryStage.setScene(scene)
    primaryStage.show()
  }
}
```

./build.sbt

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-Xlint")

val osName: SettingKey[String] = SettingKey[String]("osName")

osName := (System.getProperty("os.name") match {
    case name if name.startsWith("Linux") => "linux"
    case name if name.startsWith("Mac") => "mac"
    case name if name.startsWith("Windows") => "win"
    case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown platform!")
})

libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-base" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-controls" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-fxml" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-graphics" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx-web" % "11-ea+25" classifier osName.value

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("module-info.class") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

./project/assembly.sbt

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")
```

これはドワンゴの N 予備校プログラミングコースにある Scala 基礎編の内容です。Scala どころか、私は Java すら知らずに入門しましたが、指導と同じようにはなかなかいきません。

## 試行錯誤

JavaFX をインポートしていますが、OpenJDK 11 以降は同梱されないようなので、別途 OpenJFX をインストールしました。パスも設定したのですが、何かが正しくないらしく、ここでもまたエラーです。

配置場所と設定パス

```
$ echo $PATH_TO_FX
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/javafx-sdk-13.0.2/lib
```

```
$ java -jar ./target/scala-2.13/scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

```
$ java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ./target/scala-2.13/scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

何をどのようにすればこの問題は解決できますか。
どうかご教示いただければと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ からダウンロードした JavaFX Mac OS X SDK(13.0.2) を用いて

```
$ java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar ./target/scala-2.13/scala-gui-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

を実行してみましたが、正しく起動しました。

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

のエラーメッセージは、 `--module-path` 指定が誤っている場合に出力されるようなので、環境変数 `PATH_TO_FX` の設定値が正しいインストール先を指していないことが原因として考えられます。

---

取り敢えず起動したい、ということであれば、

```
$ sbt run
```

コマンド実行、あるいはsbtシェル上で [`run`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/ja/Running.html) と入力すれば画面が開くと思います。
(こちらの場合、JavaFX SDKのインストールなど事前準備は不要です。)

Comment: 辟易されてしまうと思いますが、`exec zsh` でシェルを再起動していなかったことが原因だったようで、`java` コマンドでパスとモジュールを指定してあっさり起動できました。`source ~/.zprofile` では反映されないのですね。大変お手数おかけしてすみません。ありがとうございました。